# Could not find the correct Provider<>

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I have a class that makes an HTTP get request and two screens the first one is displayed titles that fetched from API the second screen displays the posts that also fetched from the API and all using provider What I did is that in the main class home:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<NewsRequest>(
 child:News(title: "Bitcoin News",),
 builder: (_) => NewsRequest() ),
```

and in the two screens, I did that final

```
 newsResponse = Provider.of<NewsRequest>(context);
```

but this error appears

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Discription
>   Widget flutter: flutter: To fix, please: flutter: flutter: * Ensure
>   the Provider is an ancestor to this Discription Widget flutter: *
>   Provide types to Provider flutter:
>   * Provide types to Consumer flutter: * Provide types to Provider.of() flutter: * Always use package imports. Ex: import
>   'package:my_app/my_code.dart'; flutter:   * Ensure the
>   correctcontext` is being used.

how to solve it????

Comment: The error message already tells you what's wrong and what you should do. What don't you understand?

Comment: It's my first time with provider so I don't know what the error message meant .. what  I should do?

Answer (score 3):

ok, I solve it by wrapping the ChangeNotifierProvider into a material widget instead of the home page so the entire application could access the provider

```
 return ChangeNotifierProvider<NewsRequest>(
      builder: (_) => NewsRequest(),
          child: MaterialApp(.....)
```